# Configure Ghost to use uploaded theme for Markdown preview

Tags: ghost

I installed Ghost (0.11.2) on a my own server and uploaded a [custom theme](https://github.com/MrJuliuss/plainly). The theme shows up when viewing published content in the blog or when previewing blog posts in preview mode.

However, I have not found a way to enable the theme in the Markdown preview when editing a blog post. Is there a way to enable this, or is this a known issue in Ghost?

Answer (score 0):

The markdown preview is using the theme of the admin section, not your custom theme.